# Any T1 space having an isolated point is disconnected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

There's an example in Willard's *General Topology* that says

> 26.2 b) Any $T_1$ space having an isolated  point is disconnected.

The proof I made is:

> Lets assume that $X$ is $T_1$ with more than one point. Let $x\in X$ be the isolated point, then $\{x \}$ is an open set. Because of the hypothesis, for $y\not=x$ there exists $U_y$ neighbourhood of $y$ such that $x\not\in U_y$. Lets define $U=\bigcup_{y\not=x}U_y$, which is a non-empty open set such that $\{x\}\cap U=\varnothing$. Clearly $\{x\}\cup U\subseteq X$, and if $z\in X$ then $z=x$ or $z\not=x$; for the first case we are quickly done because $z=x\in\{x\}\cup U$, for the second case, then there exists $U_z$ nbhd of $z$ such that $x\not\in U_z$ hence $z\in U$, either case $X\subseteq\{x\}\cup U$.
>   
> This way we found a disconnection for $X$.

I want to know if this is correct, or if I missed something.

Comment: What is the definition of an isolated point, as written in the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not correct: a singleton has an isolated point and is certainly T1 and connected. So we have to assume $X$ has at least two points.

Let $x$ be the isolated point. Then $\{x\}$ is open; on the other hand, $\{x\}$ is closed because of the T1 property. Therefore $X\setminus\{x\}$ is both open and closed and $X=\{x\}\cup(X\setminus\{x\})$ is a disconnection for $X$.

Comment: I don't understand very well your second paragraph, are you already assuming that $|X|>1$? If so I don't see why $\{x\}$ is also closed, wouldn't it depend on the topology?
"_So we have to assume_ $X$ _has at least two points._" I did at the begining of the proof, or where else is needed?

Comment: @AnaGalois Yes, you set the hypothesis in your proof, but since the reported exercise lacks it, I preferred to spell it out at the outset. For the rest, a space is T1 if and only if every subset of the form $\{x\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\{x\}$ being open is the definition of an isolated point, yes; your proof is correct.

Comment: The book says: "_a point_ $p$ _is isolated iff the set_ $\{p\}$ _is open_"

Comment: Well then, you're all set